# IOS - Live streaming using MPMoviePlayerController losing video but not audio

Tags: ios, streaming, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller, audio-streaming

I am Streaming a live video (.m3u8) with MPMoviePlayerViewController, however during playback sometimes the video is lost and only the Quicktime logo is displayed, however the audio still goes on.

This happens at random times, sometimes never, maybe when the internet is not as strong as it needs, but console doesn't log any errors or changes in the playback.

Is there a way to notice when this happens and to recover the video image from the streaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how HTTP live streaming is designed to work. It will progressively choose higher or lower quality streams based on the strength of the internet connection. If the connection is not fast enough the "last resort" is to continue to play audio but no video. The only way to recover the video image in this case is to improve the speed of the internet connection.

Comment: However this only happens in live streaming, the streaming is not slow, it just stops suddenly. If I close the player and open it again (load the url again) then it starts playing smoothly both video and audio again.

IF there is no way to stop it from losing connection, is there any way to know when this happens so that I can load the URL again automatically?

Comment: You should be able to find more info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/streamingmediaguide/Introduction/Introduction.html